# Cannot import numpy in blender (2.78)

Tags: python

Here's the output from Blender python console:

```
>>> from numpy import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

It seems that Blender is trying to use my system Numpy instead of its own version. If I try importing numpy in a regular python console, it works just fine. However, the regular python console seems to use numpy from a different path than Blender:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.__path__)
['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy']
```

How to solve this?

EDIT: Inside Blender, sys.path gives:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/addons_contrib', '/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/addons', '/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/startup', '/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/modules', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/freestyle/modules', '/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/modules', '/home/myhome/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/modules']
```

In normal python console, I get:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: That question didn't really have a proper answer. Also, I thought I had exactly the same problem and I deleted the /scripts/modules directory that was causing problems for the other guy completely, but this didn't solve the problem. It is possible that my problem would be solved by forcing Blender to use numpy from another path, but how do I do this?

Comment: well, run `from numpy import version`, what does it say? and what does `print(sys.paths)` from the answer say? This should give you the answer which numpy it finds.

Comment: By the way, there is a typo: `print(sys.path)` should be correct. Run it from Blender.

Comment: I added my sys.path information above. There is a difference, but how do I add the directory my normal python console is using to Blender? Also trying to import just numpy.version gives the same error as above.

Comment: well, there is no path `yourBlenderDir/python/lib/site-packages` (this was for 2.77, so check your distribution). try adding it to the path in the beginning

Comment: so you probably need sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/blender/site/packages") or something like this. I don't have any system libs in my path at all, when running it inside blender.

Comment: I now found out that the problem is that Blender is using Python version 3.5 and for some reason the version of numpy I have doesn't work on that version of python. I installed Python 3.5 also on my regular system and importing numpy on that in regular python console also gives the same error. It seems that my Blender installation didn't come with numpy so the only choices I have is to make Blender use python3.4 somehow or install a version of numpy that works on python3.5.

Comment: well, I use 2.77a for linux and it comes with python 3.5 and numpy prepackaged. Which installation are you using?

Comment: Since I'm running a rather old version of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) and I needed a newer version of Blender for some plugin, I installed it from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender . It's of course possible that the guy maintaining the PPA just decided to not include numpy for whatever reason.

Comment: I see.. I have an even older Ubuntu :) You can just download Blender Tarball .bz2 from https://www.blender.org/download/ , unpack it and it should work out of the box. It has `blender` executable, you just run it.

Comment: Thanks! Using Blender from the tarball in blender.org worked. I don't know if I should really mark this as solved though since it's not a very clean solution.

Comment: well, it is not possible to submit an answer to this question, but you could upvote some comments, that helped your problem.

Comment: from the PPA (thomas-schiex) page linked above: "For NumPy to work with Python 3.6 on Python 3.5 based distributions (pre-artful), please install numpy with pip." No luck though for me - ended up working with the official tarbal.